# PHP check if string contains characters and if it does, wrap those character in html?

Tags: php, string

I have string that I'm trying to manipulate, for example, "Hello World"

I want to be able to check if the string contains the word "World" and if it does, wrap it in a `<span>`, so the end result would be:

```
"Hello <span>World</span>"
```

What would be the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info, http://php.net/preg_replace, or even just http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: There are many threads already on this topic. Have you tried any of those solutions and had issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str = str_replace("World", "<span>World</span>", "Hallo World!");
```

Or [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) for more complex searching

Comment: Note this would match `Worlds` as well and make it `<span>World</span>s`. Not sure what the expected behavior is in that scenario.

Comment: That is true. You could avoid that using preg_replace but if we dont know the use case we can just guess :-)